# Is is correct to say "He has too much value" meaning "He is too valuable"?

Tags: word-usage

Can the boss/colleagues say this about employee in the company, meaning he has rare skills and abilities, so it is unlikely that he will be fired even if he does something outrageous.

I googled the phrase and didn't find much, so I'm quite unsure, can it be used or not, though ***he has too much value*** seems a bit strange.

*Smoking was forbidden in the lab, but Johnson **had too much value**, and didn’t give a shit.*

*Smoking was forbidden in the lab, but Johnson **was too valuable**, and didn’t give a shit.*

Comment: Hello Tony.  Some more context please.  Who said this, about whom, in what situation, to whom?  Questions lacking context tend to get closed.

Comment: "He is too valuable" is definitely more usual. Why do you want to use this instead? Do you think it means something different, or works in a different context?

Comment: It's definitely grammatically correct, and it's been used, and [you can find examples on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+too+much+value%22).

Comment: For example, ["It has too much value for society to be lightly repudiated"](https://books.google.com/books?id=7PQ1AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA832&dq=%22has+too+much+value%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv-bqNqtX5AhXAlIkEHQilDN4Q6AF6BAgHEAI) and ["...we would not want to convert her to a combat loaded ship because she would not fit into any organization and she has too much value in the increased speed"](https://books.google.com/books?id=dLOrwAq6-PkC&pg=PA394&dq=%22she+has+too+much+value%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv5pbxqtX5AhVshYkEHYs-CnoQ6AF6BAgIEAI)

Comment: @Stuart F
Too make it active instead of passive, I think it would probably sound better

Comment: @Tuffling_Tony All of your original sentences are active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical, and both mean the same thing.

Both are also slightly weird. The usual way for such constructions to be used is as introductions for an infinitive that explains in what respect something is not appropriate.

> It was too long to fit in the box

> He was too upset to notice

> It is too late to get there on time

An infinitive is not the only way to indicate in what respect something is not appropriate

> A year’s delay was too long for his patience.

The point is that “too” is typically an introduction to more than just an adjective.

However, English also exhibits ellipsis, which is omission of certain words that the speaker or writer assumes will be understood by the intended audience. That is the case here.

> too valuable [to be fired]

> too valuable [in his special skills for his employer to risk encouraging him to look for a new employer]

The problem with ellipsis is that the exact meaning may be unclear to everyone (including the speaker).